# Trying to sort a list full of a object by the a list from that object's properties c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a class that has a bunch of different variables and a couple lists 1 in particular holds ints(positionInts)

I also have a list(teamsList) for holding objects I have created from that class

now I would like to sort the team's list by positions values

Hopefully, I'm not being too vague as the project I'm working on is full of not well-written code so it can be hard to explain.

Comment: You'll need to post some code; this is unanswerable as it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe you have a class named Team. Then you have "a bunch of different variables" (a little vague) that maybe means Properties. One particular list (List<T> maybe). Then list(teamsList) which is maybe List<Team>. Is positionints a property of Team? Do you see why this is impossible to answer as it is. Provide the code you have tried and what you expected and what happened. Also any error messages and what line of code caused them.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

This function orders the list according to your precondition.

```
private List<String> OrderList(List<String> teams, int[] positions)
{
    List<String> orderedTeams;
    Dictionary<int, string> teamsToOrder = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    int position = 0;
    foreach (string team in teams)
    {
        teamsToOrder.Add(positions[position], teams[position]);
        position = position + 1; 
    }

    orderedTeams = teamsToOrder.OrderByDescending(team => team.Key).Select(team => team.Value).ToList();

        return orderedTeams;
    }
```

Comment: Consider using `Zip` - to merge the two to avoid the need for the `Dictionary`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you have list of arbitrary type, for example list of strings:

```
var teamsList = new List<String> { "team1", "team2", "team3", "team4" };
```

Next up, you have enumeration of integers:

```
var positionInts = new[] { 2, 3, 1, 0 };
```

And your goal is to order `teamsList` based on sequence numbers of the `positionInts`. In that case you can use following method:

```
static IEnumerable<T> OrderBySequence<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<Int32> sequence)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.Min(source.Count(), sequence.Count()); i++)
    {
        var s = sequence.ElementAt(i);
        if (s > -1 && s < source.Count())
        {
            yield return source.ElementAt(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Which will produce:

```
team3
team4
team2
team1
```

Comment: Your use of `ElementAt` with an `IEnumerable` could be **super** inefficient (e.g. if source is an `IQueryable` which hits the database). You likely should change `IEnumerable<T>` to something like `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: If you don't want to do this, you should use LINQ's `Zip` to zip together `source` and `sequence`.